# c# Fill a listview with items from a richtextbox (each lines into columns, breaking at empty line and go to next row)

Tags: c#, listview, richtextbox, readline

I would like to read through a richtextbox, have each paragraph in a row and each line in the paragraph into its column.

Paragraphs are separated by an empty line

An example of the information in the richtextbox below:

[image: richtextbox example]

I'd like to have 3 columns. 
Then each first 2 lines in the paragraph be in the first two columns, then all the remaining lines into the 3rd column.

All i have right now is have it read each 3 columns into the listview as below, and this clearly does not achieve what i want.

```
for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Count(); i += 3)
   {
       listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[]{
            richTextBox1.Lines[i],
            richTextBox1.Lines[i+1], 
            richTextBox1.Lines[i+2]]}));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Add this method


  public static HashSet<Tuple<int, string, string, string>>  GetRichTextBoxSections(string[] Lines)
        {
            HashSet<Tuple<int, string, string, string>> Sections = new HashSet<Tuple<int, string, string, string>>();
            int SectionNumber = -1;
            int SectionIndexLineNumber = 0;
            bool FoundNewSectionNumber = false;
            string Col1 = string.Empty;
            string Col2 = string.Empty;
            string Col3 = string.Empty;
            int LinesCount = Lines.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < LinesCount; i++)
            {

                string NoSpaces = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Lines[i], @"\s+", "");
                if (FoundNewSectionNumber == false)
                {
                    SectionIndexLineNumber = i;
                }



                if (FoundNewSectionNumber)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(NoSpaces) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(NoSpaces) & FoundNewSectionNumber == true)
                    {

                        Sections.Add(new Tuple<int, string, string, string>(SectionNumber, Col1, Col2, Col3));
                        SectionNumber = -1;
                        FoundNewSectionNumber = false;
                        Col1 = string.Empty;
                        Col2 = string.Empty;
                        Col3 = string.Empty;
                        SectionIndexLineNumber = 0;
                        continue;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        switch (i - SectionIndexLineNumber)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                Col1 = Lines[i];
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                Col2 = Lines[i];
                                break;
                            default:
                                Col3 += Lines[i];
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (FoundNewSectionNumber == false)
                {
                    FoundNewSectionNumber = int.TryParse(NoSpaces, out SectionNumber);
                }
                if (i == (LinesCount - 1))
                {
                    Sections.Add(new Tuple<int, string, string, string>(SectionNumber, Col1, Col2, Col3));
                }
            }
            return Sections;
        }
```

**Call it like below**

```
foreach(Tuple<int,string,string,string> SectionData in GetRichTextBoxSections(richTextBox1.Lines))
            {

 listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[]{
//Item1 is the section index if you need it
            SectionData.Item2,
            SectionData.Item3, 
            SectionData.Item4}));
}
```

Comment: Hi @loannis G. Thank you.....But I am getting this error when I try run the program. "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'void' because 'void' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

Comment: Try now..Replace with the new one I just added.  
 I had changed it before but forgot to click save, let me know if it is ok or not

Comment: Alright, the error is out now. thanks. However the first line is never explicitly an integer, and yes I would like to include it in the listview. How do we not make to take only integers but strings as well?

Comment: replace every  HashSet<Tuple<int, string, string, string>>   with HashSet<Tuple<string, string, string, string>>  and this Sections.Add(new Tuple<int, string, string, string>(SectionNumber, Col1, Col2, Col3));  with Sections.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string, string>(SectionNumber.ToString(), Col1, Col2, Col3));